# Received Error in fetching the root view controller

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm new to IOS Development. I tried to find out a root view controller using the below code :

```
print("UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController : " , UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController)
```

I applied this line in two views. one view it's working fine. But another View it's getting the error like below:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray
```

Does anyone know how to solve this error?. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

For swift 5 and above use following command

```
print("UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController : " , UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, It's getting the Could not cast the value of type MyViewController.

Comment: what does it return when you print this line print("UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController : " , UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController)